# How to unit test and mock a method that takes a ModelAndView as Parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mocking

I have a i18n properties file called as

```
MessagesBundle_en.properties

invalidresourceBundle = Default locale English
invalidUserName = UserName cannot be null or empty or blank string
```

I have a class called `ParameterVerify` which verifies the parameters.

```
public class ParameterVerify {

    public void verifyParameters(String userName, ModelAndView modelAndView, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        if (resourceBundle == null) {
            resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", Locale.ENGLISH);
        }

        if (!(verifyParameter(userName))) {
            modelAndView.addObject("invalidUserName", resourceBundle.getString("invalidUserName"));
        }
    }

    private boolean verifyParameter(final String parameter) {
        if (!(StringUtils.isBlank(parameter))) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How to Test and Mock the method of the class ParameterVerify?

Comment: And? Is `ModelAndView` an interface?

Comment: No. Inbuilt class provided by spring.

Comment: That code doesn't compile. You can´t test it! What exactly do you want to test? What have you tried and what is your specific problem?

Comment: @user714965 thank you pointing it out. there was a mistake in the code. Corrected and updated it.

Comment: @user714965 I want to test that when a modelAndView is passed into the method verifyParameters, it adds an object to the modelAndView when an incorrect userName is passed. I want to assert that it was the same string from the i18n file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've hacked a unit test for you. I´m using [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) to create a mock for `ModelAndView`. Mocking the `ResourceBundle` isn't possible as the `getString()` method is `final`. So I´m using a [dummy implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030576/how-to-mock-resourcebundle-getstring) to manipulate the return value. If you have a number of those tests you should better wrap the `ResourceBundle` in an own class which is mockable and pass that around. But wait... you won't need to mock or stub the `RessourceBundle` as you can use the real `.properties` file and pass `null` here.

I wrote this test just to get you an idea about how this could work.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String userName = null; // should add message
    ModelAndView modelAndView = Mockito.mock(ModelAndView.class);
    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = new ResourceBundle() {
        @Override
        protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
            if ("invalidUserName".equals(key)) {
                return "mocked_string";
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
            return Collections.emptyEnumeration();
        }
    };

    ParameterVerify parameterVerify = new ParameterVerify();
    parameterVerify.verifyParameters(userName, modelAndView, resourceBundle);
    Mockito.verify(modelAndView, Mockito.times(1)).addObject(Mockito.eq("invalidUserName"), Mockito.eq("mocked_string"));
}
```

Better use the real `MessagesBundle_en.properties` file as test resource:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String userName = null; // should add message
    ModelAndView modelAndView = Mockito.mock(ModelAndView.class);
    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = null;

    ParameterVerify parameterVerify = new ParameterVerify();
    parameterVerify.verifyParameters(userName, modelAndView, resourceBundle);
    Mockito.verify(modelAndView, Mockito.times(1)).addObject(Mockito.eq("invalidUserName"), Mockito.eq("UserName cannot be null or empty or blank string"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect.